# Symfony Doctrine findOneBy with not equal to

Tags: symfony, doctrine, criteria

I need to find a phone number in a recording where the contract ID is not equal to current contract ID.
It is easy to find in a specific contract ID. $value is the entity instance in my custom validator.

```
$existingPhone = $this->contractRepository->findOneBy(['phone' => $value->getPhone(), 'contractId' => $value->getContractId()]);
```

but how to find in other than the current contract ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a method in your `contractRepository`, and use the Doctrine QB.

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $qb
            ->where('c.phone = :phone')
            ->andWhere(
                $qb->expr()->neq('c.contractId', 'contractId')
            )
            ->setParameters([
                'phone' => $phone,
                'contractId' => $contractId,
            ])
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
```